# Overlaying matplotlib commands on existing Cairo image surface/context

Tags: python, matplotlib, overlay, diagram, cairo

I have a diagram created from a SVG file and loaded in using the [cairosvg](https://github.com/Kozea/CairoSVG) library.

I want to further enhance this diagram with additional overlaid plots defined programatically via direct matplotlib commands.

I'm trying to do this in memory and *not* to write out to file and reload in. Only saving the final file.

However, it's proving difficult to *combine* the existing cairo with that which is being rendered by matplotlib. I thought that [this was a potential solution](http://sixdegrees.hu/blog/2010/07/plotting-igraph-graphs-in-matplotlib/), but not sure.

Simplified example:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Cairo') # Make sure here that our figures will use Cairo!
from cairosvg import surface
from cairosvg import parser
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as img 
import numpy as np

SVG='\
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500">\
<rect id="arena" x="10" y="10" width="480" height="480" fill="#ff5555" fill-opacity="0.5"/>\
</svg>\
'

svg = parser.Tree(bytestring=SVG)

surf = surface.PNGSurface(svg,None,1)
#surf.cairo.write_to_png("test-svg.png") # Can do this to see svg render to file
surf.finish() # Required?
ctx = surf.context # Can get the context here fine..

fig = plt.imshow(ctx) # <----- MAGIC REQUIRED HERE ABOUTS
#fig = plt.figure() # This works like a normal plot - but no svg

ax = fig.gca() # Create some overlay data
x = np.array(np.random.randn(100))
y = np.array(np.random.randn(100))
ax.plot(x,y)

plt.savefig("test-final.png") # Save svg & overlay plot
```

**EDIT:** also been trying the following, based on earlier above link. Still no joy though.

```
from matplotlib.artist import Artist

class SurfArtist(Artist):
  def __init__(self,surf):
    Artist.__init__(self)
    self._surf = surf

  def draw(self,renderer):
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_cairo import RendererCairo
    if not isinstance(renderer, RendererCairo):
      raise TypeError("backend not supported")
    ctx = renderer.gc.ctx if hasattr(renderer, "gc") else renderer.ctx
    self._surf.context = ctx
    self._surf.cairo.show_page()

...

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
surf_artist = SurfArtist(surf)
surf_artist.set_zorder(float('inf'))
ax.artists.append(surf_artist)
```

Comment: That call to 'surf.finish()' looks fishy. This means that you are done with the surface and it can throw all its data away. I guess the next call to 'surf.context' already fails due to this. Could you check the context's status? I guess via printing 'ctx.status'. What happens if you just don't call 'surf.finish()'?

Comment: @UliSchlachter - good point about finish(). Looking at cairosvg src it does seem to output all it's data. However, removing it still causes the same error: TypeError: Image data can not convert to float. Sadly I can't find any method for status from a cairo.Context neither (http://cairographics.org/documentation/pycairo/2/reference/context.html)

Answer (score 0):

Code below should works, convert the surface to numpy array first as in https://github.com/Kozea/CairoSVG/issues/57

```
matplotlib.use('Cairo') # Make sure here that our figures will use Cairo!
from cairosvg import surface
from cairosvg import parser
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as img 
import numpy as np

# function to convert to array
def surface_to_npim(surface):
    """ Transforms a Cairo surface into a numpy array. """
    im = +np.frombuffer(surface.get_data(), np.uint8)
    H,W = surface.get_height(), surface.get_width()
    im.shape = (H,W, 4) # for RGBA
    return im[:,:,:3]


SVG='\
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500">\
<rect id="arena" x="10" y="10" width="480" height="480" fill="#ff5555" fill-opacity="0.5"/>\
</svg>\
'

svg = parser.Tree(bytestring=SVG)

surf = surface.PNGSurface(svg,None,1)
#surf.cairo.write_to_png("test-svg.png") # Can do this to see svg render to file
surf.finish() # Required?


# convert svg and plot
img = surface_to_npim(surf.cairo)
plt.imshow(img)

# Create some overlay data
x = np.array(np.random.randn(100))
y = np.array(np.random.randn(100))
plt.plot(x,y)

plt.savefig("test-final.png") # Save svg & overlay plot
```